# Projectile motion on a wedge

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

A plane is inclined at an angle $\beta$ from the ground and a particle is launched at angle $\alpha-\beta$ from the plane with initial velocity $u$ such that it hits the plane at right angle to the plane. We have to show $\cot\beta= 2\tan(\alpha-\beta)$. Can you show it using the trd equation of motion $v^{2}= u^{2} +2as$ applied along the plane direction?

Comment: Could you please solve by taking  initial velocity horizontally along wedge and range along the wedge i.e ucos(α-β) ,2u²sin(α-β)cosα/g(cosβ)^2 respectively and plug it in v² = u² + 2as, where v=0 and a=-gsinβ, I'm not able to get the result this way, please help brother

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use appropriate SUVAT equations in **both** the parallel and perpendicular directions, not just the parallel direction.

The equations you need are:

$$\dot{x}=u\cos(\alpha-\beta)-gt\sin\beta$$
$$y=ut\sin(\alpha-\beta)-\frac12gt^2\cos\beta$$

You just have to set $\dot{x}=0$ for the same value of $t$ for which $y=0$ and the result follows immediately

Comment: Could you please solve by taking initial velocity horizontally along wedge and range along the wedge i.e ucos(α-β) ,2u²sin(α-β)cosα/g(cosβ)^2 respectively and plug it in v² = u² + 2as, where v=0 and a=-gsinβ, I'm not able to get the result this way, please help brother

Comment: Why would you want to do it this way? What you're suggesting is far more complicated, and pre-supposes that you have the formula for the range already, which needs to be derived, surely? Perhaps you should post an new, more specific, question about this, and show what you have tried yourself.

Comment: Yeah pre supposing the formula for range along wedge, which is very easily derivable, I'm trying the aforesaid way. My specific doubt is that I have got the answer the way you told, but why isn't the answer matching if I try the above, could you please also try it this way only, It'll be helpful brother please

Answer (score 0):

$u$ along incline = $u.cos(\alpha - \beta)$

$a$ along incline = $a.sin(\beta)$

---

$u$ perpendicular to incline = $u.sin(\alpha - \beta)$
$a$ perpendicular to incline = $a.cos(\beta)$

---

Using 1st equations of motion in x-direction (along the incline)

$0 = u.cos(\alpha - \beta) - a.sin(\beta).t$

From this we get

t = $u.cos(\alpha - \beta) / a.sin(\beta)$

---

Also in y-direction displacement = 0

so $t = 2.u.sin(\alpha - \beta) / a.cos(\beta)$  [Using 2nd equation of motion]

---

Using above two values of $t$

$u.cos(\alpha - \beta) / a.sin(\beta) = 2.u.sin(\alpha - \beta) / a.cos(\beta)$

$=> cot(\beta) = 2.tan(\alpha - \beta)$

---

Comment: Bro could you please try it the way I have suggested above